# Using Grouping Set with multiple count columns

Tags: sql, count, grouping

I am trying to get a count of three specific things for each computer manufacturer-model combo I have in my database. Those three things are the numbers of combos, the number of students who have borrowed each combo, and the total times the computer has been borrowed. The last two are different because a student can borrow the same combo more than once. The last part is to get a grand total for each column (this seems to be working incorrectly in my query). I have developed the following query.

```
SELECT item_manuf||'-'|| item_model "item", 
    count(DISTINCT comp_id) "Num Comps", 
    count(DISTINCT st_id) "Num Users", 
    count(loan_id) "Num Loans"
FROM computer 
JOIN item USING (item_id)
JOIN loan USING (comp_id)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Item_Manuf, 
    Item_Model),());
```

And the resulting tables:

```
item                                                 Num Comps  Num Users  Num Loans
--------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Acer-Aspire                                                  1          1          1
Apple-Macbook Air                                            1          1          1
Apple-Macbook Pro                                            1          1          1
Dell-Alienware                                               1          1          1
Dell-Inspiron                                                2          3          3
HP-Elitebook                                                 2          3          3
HP-Envy                                                      2          1          2
HP-Pavilion                                                  3          2          3
HP-Stream Notebook                                           1          1          1
Lenovo-ThinkPad                                              1          3          3
-                                                           15         10         19

11 rows selected.
```

The counts in each specific combos row are correct. I have verified that with the raw data. However, the grand total received for number of users is not correct. I have done some investigating and noticed that the grouping sets is giving me the total count of students we have in the database. Not a total count of unique student-manuf-model combinations. I believe this is also happening with the other two grand totals, but it is the correct result. Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: which part of the query is obtaining the bottom counts of 15,10,19....to me it looks like your only getting the counts for each manuf and model combo, not total for each col

Comment: Never mind, didn't know what grouping sets did.....try taking distinct out of your count

Comment: Taking distinct out gets me the same count as the last column

Answer (score 0):

GROUPING SETS doesn't give you grand total in your case. The equivalent query is:

```
SELECT item_manuf||'-'|| item_model "item", 
    count(DISTINCT comp_id) "Num Comps", 
    count(DISTINCT st_id) "Num Users", 
    count(loan_id) "Num Loans"
FROM computer 
JOIN item USING (item_id)
JOIN loan USING (comp_id)
GROUP BY Item_Manuf, Item_Model
UNION ALL
SELECT null, 
    count(DISTINCT comp_id) "Num Comps", 
    count(DISTINCT st_id) "Num Users", 
    count(loan_id) "Num Loans"
FROM computer 
JOIN item USING (item_id)
JOIN loan USING (comp_id);
```

Comment: This actually gives me the same result as the above query. Can I union and then SUM up each of the columns?

Comment: @kirie It gives you the same because I tried to explain how grouping sets works - it just unite different groupings together

Comment: @kirie Are you sure the sum will give anything useful here?

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Thank you for the explanation. Well I thought about how to create pivot tables and we use the sum of counts for those.